# Python Coinbase API warning for insecure endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, coinbase-api

## The Problem

Working my way through the documentation on the [coinbase developer page](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/guides/bitcoin-wallet) and when running the most basic example I get a warning about insecure endpoints. I'd like to solve this warning before moving on.

## The Warning

> python3.5/site-packages/coinbase/wallet/util.py:45: UserWarning:
>   WARNING: this client is sending a request to an insecure API endpoint.
>   Any API request you make may expose your API key and secret to third
>   parties. Consider using the default endpoint:

## The Code

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
from vars import *

client = Client (   
    API_KEY,
    API_SECRET,
    API_VERSION)

print(client.get_accounts)
```

vars is a file that contains my constants; key, secret, and version.

## The Attempts

In all honesty, just a host of google searches that don't seem to be turning up anything useful, in regards to setting the endpoint. Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the versioning parameter appears to have *at least **silenced*** the warning.

```
client = Client (   
        API_KEY,
        API_SECRET)
```